Can anyone help me decipher these dodge and burn effects from a PSD
I got this PSD from a guy gracious enough to share them with me. I cannot decipher these Dodge and burn methods. Anyone experienced enough to eyeball and break this down?
This layer made wrinkes disappear. This HAD to be a selection made, right?

This layer i know whats going on

This layer im ALL confused about! He labeled it skintone. How do i do this?


Off-hand they look like High Pass layers.
